# meteor: how to debug a non-working ES6 export import?

Tags: javascript, meteor, module, ecmascript-6

I'm using ES6 with meteor's ECMAScript package. I'm trying to develop my own package an have run into an issue that I don't know how to approach debugging.

In my package I have a module that is the main entry point `main.js`. In the module I import another module`import '../imports/startup/client/index.js';`

In `index.js` I export a function a function. Right before I export this I check that it is defined and everything:

```
console.log(ExportedFunction)
export const Exportedfunction = ExportedFunction;
```

console returns:

```
ExportedFunction(opts) {                                                                                        
    _classCallCheck(this, ExportedFunction);
```

Then in my example app I try to use that export:

```
import { Exportedfunction } from 'meteor/packageauthor:packagename'
console.log(Exportedfunction)
```

console returns:

```
undefined
```

So somewhere the export/import breaks but I don't know how to figure out why.

What are general steps to debug this type of failure?

Edit: It seems that exporting within a nested module is the issues. If I bring the same `export const Exportedfunction = ExportedFunction;` into `main.js` instead of importing it in `index.js` then everything works.

Why is this and/or how do I fix that so I can export from a module imported by another module?

Comment: I thought meteor doesn't yet use modules for packages? i.e., your export doesn't do what you think it does. Can you show us your package.js?

Comment: As of Meteor 1.3 I think modules in packages works just fine. There isn't much in my package.js due to this. api.mainModule is about the only relevant thing.  A slightly older but working version is here https://github.com/prosemeteor/prosemirror/blob/master/package.js That one seemingly works because the export is in the mainModule and not some nested file that is imported from the mainmodule like I want to do.  I think the relevant question remains if i didn't happen to stumble on a solution how could I have debugged my way there?

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same problem. Did you found a way to solve this?

Comment: The problem was a circular import (file "a" has: import b from 'b.js', file "b" has: import a from 'a.js').

Comment: How do you solve that kind of circular import? How did you find out circular import would return `undefined`?